# Assigning value from cursor to the text field in Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a cursor which is returning certain value. I would like to assign this value to a text field. When I compile trigger it returns error: "bad bind variable" for new_dr.textitem43. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
declare
    EMP_ID_VALUE number :='NEW_EMP.ID_FIELD';
    pcv_no     pcv%TYPE;

cursor cursor_dr IS
  select pcv FROM drivers 
  where drivers.eno = EMP_ID_VALUE;

begin
  IF EMP_ID_VALUE < 1000 THEN

  open cursor_dr;

  fetch cursor_dr into pcv_no; 
  :new_dr.textitem43 := 'pcv_no';
  exit when cursor_dr%NOTFOUND;
  CLOSE cursor_dr;

  ELSIF
 ...
END IF;
```

end;

Comment: Your first assignment is to a string `'NEW_EMP.ID_FIELD'`. I think you want to get the value from the item, so you should use `EMP_ID_VALUE number := :NEW_EMP.ID_FIELD;`

Comment: Also, you probably want to assign the variable pcv_no, not the string constant: :new_dr.textitem43 := pcv_no;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would indicate to me that either there is no block named new_dr or there is no field named textitem43 in that block.  Are you sure you don't really mean :new_emp.textitem43?